# Accept TCP/IPv4 Server

Tags: c++, class, serversocket

I have implemented a server function in my class and want to accept a remote connection via accept but unfortunately a connection from 0.0.0.0 via port 0 is accepted.

I have found this question a couple of times here but there was the solution that the `adr_len` was not initialized with the size of `sockaddr_in` client and this leads to the error when passing it to (with 0) to the accept function. But I initialize mine with the corresponding size (16) and I still have this behavior.

**terminal output:**

```
Initialization successfully completed
Start TCP/-IPv4 server service
Server thread is decoupled
Waiting for remote connection status: 0
adrLen = 16
0.0.0.0 connection via port 0
Wait for remote connection status: 4
Connected to 0.0.0.0: established!
```

**connection.cpp:**

```
#include "connection.h"
//Für aus Chrono generierter resume Zeit
using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;

//Standart-Konstruktor
connection::connection(const SOCKET &listenSock_Handle)
: Status(0)
, isWaitRead(false)
, isWrite(false)
, listenSock(listenSock_Handle)
{
    //Speicherbereiche initialiseren
    ZeroMemory((SOCKET*)&remoteSock,sizeof(remoteSock));
    ZeroMemory((sockaddr_in*)&client,sizeof(client));
    ZeroMemory(remoteName,NI_MAXHOST);
    ZeroMemory(remoteService,NI_MAXSERV);
    ZeroMemory(recvBuffer,sizeof(recvBuffer));
    ZeroMemory(sendBuffer,sizeof(sendBuffer));  
}
//Standart-Destruktor 
connection::~connection()
{
    //Socket schliessen
    closesocket(remoteSock);
}
//Eingehende Verbindungen annehmen  und Client abspalten
//Diese Klasse bildet dann die Verbindung mit diesem Client ab
//Danach wird durch den Thread auf Daten an dem Socket gewartet und diese
//in den Reiceved Buffer geladen
void connection::startUp(){
    std::thread wait_for_Request { [&] (){
        //adrLen muss zuerst mit der sockadr_in größe initialisert werden bevor diese an accept übergeben wird
        int adrLen = sizeof(client);
        std::cout << "adrLen = " << adrLen << std::endl;
        mx_Status.lock();
        Status = 1;                                                                             
        mx_Status.unlock();
        remoteSock = accept(listenSock,(sockaddr*)&client,&adrLen);
        if (remoteSock == INVALID_SOCKET){
            WSAGetLastError();
            mx_Status.lock();
            Status = -1;  
            mx_Status.unlock();   
        }
        mx_Status.lock();
        Status = 2;
        mx_Status.unlock();
        if(getnameinfo((sockaddr*)&client,adrLen, remoteName,NI_MAXHOST,remoteService,NI_MAXSERV,0) == 0){
            mx_Status.lock();
            Status = 3; 
            mx_Status.unlock();   
        }
        else{
            inet_ntop(AF_INET,&client.sin_addr,remoteName,NI_MAXHOST);
            // this->remoteService = ntohs(this->client.sin_port);
            std::cout << remoteName << " verbindnung ueber port " << ntohs(client.sin_port) << std::endl;  
            mx_Status.lock();
            Status = 4;
            mx_Status.unlock();
        }
        //Client Verbindung hergestellt beginne Daten von Socket zu lesen
        do
        {
            //Lese daten von Socket und schreibe diese in Puffer.
            mx_isWaitRead.lock();
            isWaitRead = true;
            mx_isWaitRead.unlock();
            mx_recvBuff.lock();
            int bytesReceived = recv(remoteSock,recvBuffer,4095,0);
            mx_recvBuff.unlock();
            mx_isWaitRead.lock();
            isWaitRead = false;
            mx_isWaitRead.unlock();
            if (bytesReceived < 0){
                WSAGetLastError();
                mx_Status.lock();
                int Status = -1;
                mx_Status.unlock();
            }else if (bytesReceived == 0){
                mx_Status.lock();
                Status = 5;
                mx_Status.unlock();
            }
            //Resume Zeit 75MS
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(0.075s);
        } while (true);     
    }}; 
    wait_for_Request.join();
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //Server-Dienst 
    std::shared_ptr<SOCKET> listening(new SOCKET(0));                           //ptr auf Socket handle erstellen.
    //TCP-Server Dienst initialiseren                                           //Wenn erfolgreich dann Status 0
    if (initialisierung::initialize_Server(0,listening) == 0){                                    //WinSock initial. & Bind (TCP/IPv4 + PORT) = 0 default Port 
        //Initialisierung war erfolgreich
        //dann erstelle neues "connection Objekt"
        connection * Verbindung = new connection(*listening);
        
        //Thread für neue Verbindung starten
        std::cout<<"TCP/-IPv4 Serverdienst starten"<<std::endl;
        std::thread manageRemoteVerbindung ([&]{Verbindung->startUp();});
        std::cout<< "Serverthread ist entkoppelt"<< std::endl;
        
        //Warte auf eingehende Verbindung
        while(Verbindung->getState() == 0 || Verbindung->getState() == 1) 
        {
            std::cout<< "Warte auf Remote Verbindungsstatus: "<< Verbindung->getState() << std::endl;          
            Sleep(1500);
        }        
        std::cout<< "Warte auf Remote Verbindungsstatus: "<< Verbindung->getState() << std::endl;
        std::cout<< "Verbunden mit "<< Verbindung->getClientInfo() <<" hergestellt!"<< std::endl;
        while(getchar() != '\n');
```

Comment: You should probably post the implementation of `getClientInfo()` and the definition of your `connection` class. It's also better to post the source that matches the output you show. (The source you posted has all the output in German, but the log you posted is in English).

Answer (score 0):

Since somebody actually connected, the problem is clearly calling `getpeername()` or its local equivalent too soon, or perhaps not at all. Only call `getpeername()` on the socket returned by `accept()`. Thus, you think 0.0.0.0 connected.

Or more likely you ignored the return value from `listen()` (code not present). While `accept()` can fail it almost never does so. One of the reasons for it to fail is `listen()` failed first.

Comment: Alternatively, since `accept()` directly outputs the address/port of the accepted client, there is really no need to call `getpeername()` separately at all.

Comment: Yep. What the asker needs should be waiting for them in `client`

Comment: @user4581301: Considering that getnameinfo() failed when he's testing on the local machine, I don't think anything's waiting for him in `client`.

Comment: I agree. I think `accept` failed. The code shouldn't continue on expecting a socket after the `accept` call fails. At the very least they should output an error message.